# Can't boot Windows (Windows and Ubuntu dual boot)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, dualboot

I recently installed Ubuntu. I wanted to make it dual boot with Windows so I made multiple partitions. I can't boot to Windows.

My boot menu looks like this:

[image]

A `boot-info` report is available [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6DyFPPd9WR/).

The OS's listed by the report:

```
OS#1:   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS CurrentSession on sda8
OS#2:   Windows Recovery Environment (boot) on sda7
OS#3:   Windows 8 or 10 on sda3
```

When I pick *Windows Recovery Environment*:

[image]

**Note:** I am booting in legacy mode.

I tried adding manual entries for Windows 10 but both go to the image above.

How can I boot Windows?

Comment: what happens when you pick windows recovery environment? And was windows installed under secureboot/non legacy mode initially?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek added image. Yes it was

Comment: Boot to WinRE, else WinPE (Windows installUSB: once GUI loads, `SHIFT`+`F10` to open a terminal), then issue: `bootrec /fixmbr && bootrec /rebuildbcd` > answer `Y` if it finds an OS; if it doesn't, that's fine too > Reboot and try to boot to Windows.  If you cannot: boot back to WinRE/WinPE either use `bcdboot` to rebuild the EFI boot files, or mount the EFI partition via `diskpart`, then copy the files from `C:\Windows\Boot\EFI` to the EFI partition _(normally the root of, but may be inside of a nested folder with dual boot)_. Upon `cd` to the EFI partition, `bootrec /fixboot` may also work.

Comment: @JW0914 I can't open a Terminal, the WinRE screen is like the image above

Comment: @Daniil Then boot WinPE (a Windows install USB) as mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: @JW0914 I don't want to re-install Windows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108979/discussion-between-daniil-and-jw0914).

Comment: @Daniil _**Please READ what I wrote in the comment... where does it say to reinstall Widows?_** If you installed Windows in UEFI, non-CSM, mode, you must be in the same mode to boot Windows... this is not a hot-swappable option. Best of luck =]

Comment: Turn secure boot back on... Reinstall Ubuntu. Ubuntu has support for secure boot installs